# extract features for similar file name

Tags: python, feature-extraction

I have some files like

```
shghgssd_1212.jpg
shghgssd_ewewe.jpg
shghgssd_opopo.jpg
sdsdsdj_weuwie.jpg
sdsdsdj_12143.jpg
sdsdsdj_eteyyw.jpg
```

and need to get a sum of their vectors but  for those whose names start with the same name until this sign `" _ "`  as

```
shghgssd_1212.jpg
shghgssd_ewewe.jpg
shghgssd_opopo.jpg
```

and those

```
sdsdsdj_weuwie.jpg
sdsdsdj_12143.jpg
sdsdsdj_eteyyw.jpg
```

also starts with the same name, I need to save the sum of their vectors

I tried like that

```
def extract_features(directory):    
    results = []
    names = [] 
    for name in listdir(directory):    
        filename=directory + '/' + name
        names.append(name)
    for name in listdir(directory):
        for n in names:
            if (name is n):
                image= load_img(filename, target_size=(224, 224,3))
                vec=model(preprocess(image).unsqueeze(0).cuda())
                vec1 = vec.sum(dim=0).cpu().detach().numpy()
                for ind in range(batch_size):
                    results.append(vec1[ind])
    return results
```

but got nothing extracted as I couldn't catch the file_name that starts with the same name

is there any better solution, please?

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? Printing variable values within your loops to see if they are what you think they are? [How to Debug Small Programs](https://www.google.com/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a example of grouping the files properly in a dictionary with each key being the relevant name before the underscore (`_`) and the values being the paths to the files using said name.

```py
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

path = Path("path/to/dir")


def group_files(directory: Path, ext="jpg"):  # We must use a pathlib object here
    # We can glob the pathlib object with our preferred extension
    list_of_files = list(map(lambda x : x.name, directory.glob(f"**/*.{ext}")))
    file_dict = defaultdict(list)  # File storage in a dict
    keyfunc = lambda x: x.split("_")[0]  # Split on the '_' and get the first word
    data = sorted(list_of_files, key=keyfunc)  # sort on the name before the '_'
    for k, g in groupby(data, keyfunc):
        file_dict[k] = list(g)
    return file_dict


dict_of_files = group_files(path)

# Now we have something like
# {"shghgssd" : ["shghgssd_1212.jpg", "shghgssd_ewewe.jpg", "shghgssd_opopo.jpg"]}
# But with full paths, not printed for brevity
# This means that you can iterate of the keys and values and get some operation going

sums_of_vecs = []
for key, value in dict_of_files.items():  # key is a string, value is a list
    print(f"Treating the files with the {key}_... prefix")
    for filepath in value:
        # DO YOUR COMPUTATION HERE
        # APPEND TO RESULTS
        pass  # nothing happens here...
```

Note that if you're controlling how the files are created, it might be better to put each batch you're planning to treat further in its own directory and then load them with [`image_dataset_from_directory`](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/).

Comment: Thanks a lot i tried but got `ValueError: Invalid pattern: '**' can only be an entire path component`

Comment: @sammo There was a typo with a dot that wasn't meant to be there, can try again!

Comment: i got `AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'split'` at this line `keyfunc = lambda x: x.split("_")[0] `

Comment: Yep, I had to check it out on my own path my bad, you need to extract the name of the files, otherwise it returns the whole path, this should be fixed.

Comment: The thing is, keeping the whole path can we useful if you're not in the directory where the files are. So you could also modify the function like `keyfunc = lambda x : x.name.split("_")[0]`. It's up to you and how you want to use the code

Comment: thanks a lot i got another error but i checked it in this line `for key, value in dict_of_files:` to be `for key, value in dict_of_files.items(): `

Comment: excuse now can i loop in every list in the dictionary to sum the vectors ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245132/discussion-between-nathan-furnal-and-sammo).